# socket recv read no message

Tags: c++, sockets

The following code is an application supposed to be communicating between two applications. In one exe (A) user type a message and the message is printed in the other exe(B).

The flow of the program:

1. Both exe calls connectTo so they are ready to send and receive messages between.
2. User type a message to be send in A console window, which calls sendMsg in A exe. When message is received in B, the message is printed in B console window.

The problem is that the message received is sometimes empty. When I enter 1234 ten times in A, ten messages are printed in B with only 5-6 of them are 1234 and the rest are empty. The situation is the same from B to A.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++
**whole program**
++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Header.h

```
#pragma once

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class CommuWin
{
private:
    std::mutex m_accessMutexSend;
    std::mutex m_accessMutexReceive;
    std::thread m_sendThread;
    std::thread m_receiveThread;
    bool m_IsSendReady = false;
    bool m_IsRecvReady = false;
    SOCKET m_outSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN m_outAddr;
    SOCKET m_inSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN m_inAddr;

public:
    CommuWin(int InPort, int OutPort);
    ~CommuWin();
    int connectTo();
    int sendMsg(const char* message);
    int StartReceiveMsg();
    bool GetRecvStatus();
    bool GetSendStatus();
private:
    void SetRecvStatus(bool ready);
    void SetSendStatus(bool ready);
    int SetupRecvEnd();
    int SetupSendEnd();
    int sendMsgTo(const char* message);
    int ReceiveMsgFrom();

};
```

Source.cpp

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include "Header.h"
#define OKAY (1)
#define ERROR (-1)
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE (200)
class NetworkServices
{
public:
    static int sendMessage(SOCKET curSocket, const char* message, int messageSize);
    static int receiveMessage(SOCKET curSocket, char * buffer, int bufSize);
};
int NetworkServices::sendMessage(SOCKET curSocket, const char* message, int messageSize)
{
    return send(curSocket, message, messageSize, 0);
}
int NetworkServices::receiveMessage(SOCKET curSocket, char * buffer, int bufSize)
{
    return recv(curSocket, buffer, bufSize, 0);
}
CommuWin::CommuWin(int InPort, int OutPort)
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion;
    DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    int r = WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    m_outSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    m_outAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    m_outAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    m_outAddr.sin_port = htons(OutPort);
    m_inSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    m_inAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    m_inAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    m_inAddr.sin_port = htons(InPort);
}
CommuWin::~CommuWin()
{   
}
int CommuWin::connectTo()
{
    printf("connect to");
    printf("\n");
    m_sendThread = std::thread(
        &CommuWin::SetupSendEnd,
        this);
    m_receiveThread = std::thread(
        &CommuWin::SetupRecvEnd,
        this);
    return OKAY;
}
int CommuWin::SetupSendEnd()
{
    SOCKET sListen; 
    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&m_outAddr, sizeof(m_outAddr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);
    m_outSocket = accept(sListen, NULL, NULL);
    if (m_outSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        SetSendStatus(true);
        printf("accepted\n");
    }
    return OKAY;
}
int CommuWin::SetupRecvEnd()
{
    int connectSucceed = 0;
    do
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        connectSucceed = connect(m_inSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&m_inAddr, sizeof(m_inAddr));

    } while (connectSucceed == SOCKET_ERROR);
    SetRecvStatus(true);
    printf("connected\n");
    return OKAY;
}
int CommuWin::sendMsg(const char* message)
{
    if (GetSendStatus())
    {
        m_sendThread.detach();
        m_sendThread = std::thread(
            &CommuWin::sendMsgTo,
            this,
            message);
    }
    return OKAY;
}
int CommuWin::sendMsgTo(const char* message)
{
    NetworkServices::sendMessage(m_outSocket, message, (int)strlen(message));
    return OKAY;
}
int CommuWin::StartReceiveMsg()
{
    if (GetRecvStatus())
    {
        m_receiveThread.detach();
        m_receiveThread = std::thread(
            &CommuWin::ReceiveMsgFrom,
            this);
    }
    return OKAY;
}
int CommuWin::ReceiveMsgFrom()
{
    while (true)
    {
        char message[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
        ZeroMemory(message, MAX_MSG_SIZE);
        NetworkServices::receiveMessage(m_inSocket, message, sizeof(message));
        printf(message);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return OKAY;
}
void CommuWin::SetRecvStatus(bool ready)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_accessMutexReceive);
    m_IsRecvReady = ready;

}
void CommuWin::SetSendStatus(bool ready)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_accessMutexSend);
    m_IsSendReady = ready;
}

bool CommuWin::GetRecvStatus()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_accessMutexReceive);
    return m_IsRecvReady;
}
bool CommuWin::GetSendStatus()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_accessMutexSend);
    return m_IsSendReady;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << argc <<std::endl;
    int Inport = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    int Outport = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    //std::cout << "inport = " << argv[1] << " outport = " << argv[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "inport = " << Inport << " outport = " << Outport << std::endl;
    CommuWin com(Inport, Outport);
    com.connectTo();
    while (true)
    {
        if (com.GetSendStatus() && com.GetRecvStatus())
        {
            com.StartReceiveMsg();
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter Send Message" << std::endl;
        std::string msg;
        std::cin >> msg;
        com.sendMsg(msg.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's kind of a lot for someone to sift through - consider narrowing down the code to just the relevant parts and perhaps add more details to the problem statement

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: You should remove redundant empty lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. First of all, you need to check results of all the functions, including, but not limited to, to `sListen`, `bind`, `listen`, `recv`.

```
 NetworkServices::receiveMessage(m_inSocket, message, sizeof(message));
 // Without checking recv result there is no way to guess how much
 // bytes are actually stored in `message`, if any. Also boldly assuming
 // that `message` is null terminated and represents a proper format string
 // is dangerous.
 printf(message);
```

You also need to carefully initialize all the stuff, especially `sockaddr` structures, which may get potentially partially initialized in this case. You are using multiple threads but perform insufficient synchronization. Method `sendMsgTo(const char* message)` executed by (potentially detached) background thread receives a pointer to a string buffer that may get invalidated at any time.

Comment: Method sendMsgTo(const char* message) executed by (potentially detached) background thread receives a pointer to a string buffer that may get invalidated at any time. --> this is my problem.

Comment: Would you elaborate more on the statement "You are using multiple threads but perform insufficient synchronization"?

Comment: @RonaldKu Typically threads should never be detached. `ReceiveMsgFrom` will never exit so you have a thread leak. Even though you are using received data only to print it things may still go wrong because `printf` output may be reordered. Actually there is no need to use threads here at all. Just use async read/write.

Comment: I am using ReceiveMsgFrom to keep receiving any data sent from the other exe. At the moment, I am still finding a way to terminate it properly when the program exits. I am open to any better design and the current one is my best design at the moment.  For async read/write, do you mean std::future and std::async?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send and receive messages, you have to write some code to do that. Nowhere is there any code to send or receive messages. If you think there is, point specifically to the code that figures out whether or not the data you received is one or more messages. You cannot do it.

TCP is *not* a message protocol. If you need a message protocol on top of TCP, you have to implement one. Have a look at protocols that do this such as HTTP, IRC, or FTP so see how it's done.

If you log the number of bytes received, you will see that all the data you sent was received. It's your job to split that data into messages if you need to -- it won't happen by itself.